# 3DF Zephyr -> Fusion 360 set mesh dimensions

Tags: fusion360, dimensional-accuracy

I have managed to successfully scan an object with 3DF Zephyr Free, and have exported the mesh to a .obj file (only filetype supported).

Once I have inserted the mesh in Fusion 360, how do I set the dimensions of the mesh?

When I import the mesh into Bambu Studio, it shows me the bounding box dimensions. So I can scale it accordingly. I can't even get a bounding box to display in Fusion 360.